# Rails View: Association :company not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, view

There is a User model and Company model.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
```

Company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

New.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>

<% if policy_scope(Company).count <= 1 %>
  <%= f.label :company, "Company: "%><br />
  <%= f.text_field :company, :value => policy_scope(Company).first %><br /><br />
  <% else %> 
  <%= f.association :company, collection: policy_scope(Company).all, prompt: "Choose a Company", :required => true %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.input :username, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :display_name, :required => true %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`f.association` is failing saying :company not found.  If `policy_scope(Company).count <= 1` then code in that condition works fine.

Please say if you need more code.  Thank you

Comment: Try `<%= f.text_field :company_id, :value => policy_scope(Company).first.id %>`

Comment: that works if I want the Company set to the first on the list but I need to give a drop down list of Companies to select from..